# Eigen values product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

$ M= \left[ {
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{array} } \right] $

What is the product of positive eigen values for the above matrix ?

I got the answer using normal method(by transforming to echelon form) to find the eigen values but it took me a lot of time.

Is there any shortcut or simple way to solve this ? After looking at the structure of the matrix, it seems that there is some shorter way to do it but I am not able to find it.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you know that the product of the eigenvalues equals the determinant?

Comment: Well: $M= uu^T + vv ^T$ for $u = e_1 + e_5$ and $v=e_2 + e_3 + e_4$. That works obviously only here...

Comment: @omkarGirkar Determinant will be 0 but I am interested in product of non zero eigen values and the answer is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notably, the matrix $M$ has rank $2$, which is to say that it will have $2$ non-zero eigenvalues.  Both of these eigenvalues will be positive, since the matrix is positive semidefinite.

Let $\lambda_i$ denote the eigenvalues of $M$. We can note that 
$$
\operatorname{tr}(M^2) = \sum_{i}\lambda_i^2\\
\operatorname{tr}(M)^2 = \left(\sum_{i}\lambda_i \right)^2 = \sum_{i, j} \lambda_i\lambda_j
$$
So that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(M)^2 - \operatorname{tr}(M^2) = \sum_{i \neq j} \lambda_i\lambda_j
$$
In other words, we can compute the product of the eigenvalues of this rank-2 positive definite matrix as
$$
\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = \frac 12\left[\operatorname{tr}(M)^2 - \operatorname{tr}(M^2) \right]
$$

---

On the other hand, we can find a permutation matrix $P$ such that
$$
PMP^T = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1\\&&1&1&1\\&&1&1&1\\&&1&1&1}
$$
Since this matrix is block-diagonal, it isn't difficult to see that the non-zero eigenvalues of the individual blocks (and hence of the entire matrix) will be $2$ and $3$ (respectively).

Comment: Does row transformation always change the eigen values ? Can we apply row or column transformation here directly on matrix ?

Comment: @Zephyr yes, applying row-transformations generally changes the eigenvalues.  One thing we can do without changing the eigenvalues, however, is apply a row-operation **and** the complementary column operation, as is indicated with the $P$ and $P^T$ bit at the end.  In this case, shifting the rows down cyclically and then shifting the columns right (again, cyclically) brings us to the second matrix I've written, which will necessarily have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: So if I interchange row 1 and row 4, then should I also interchange column 1 and column 4 to negate the effect?

Comment: @Zephyr that's right; doing that will keep the eigenvalues the same

Comment: @Zephyr [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) says a little bit about block-diagonal matriices.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously $M$ has rank two. Therefore M has only two non-negative eigenvalues(**count with multplicity**).

It is easy to check that $v_2 =(1,0,0,0,1)^T$ is an eigenvector associate to the eigenvalue 2. and $v_3 =(0,1,1,1,0)^T$ is an eigenvector associate to the eigenvalue 3. 
 $$Mv_2 =2v_2~~~and ~~~~Mv_3 =3v_3$$

> Answer is $2\times 3 = 6.$

Comment: I am interested in product of non zero eigen values and answer is 6, not 0

Comment: You did not mention that in your question

Comment: @GuyFsone he did.

Comment: I read that eigen values may change after row transformations. How are you applying row transformations?

Comment: @Zephyr you are right that happen when one multiply some line or some rows by scalar. which we did do use here.

Comment: @GuyFsone Ok thanks. Also, can you give any link which states that eigen values of entire matrix is same as that of one particular block ? I am hearing it  for the first time.

Comment: Also I don't understand why row transformation doesn't affect the eigen values. Though determinant remains the same after row transformation, but trace might change so characteristic equation can change and hence the eigen values. Right?

Comment: @Zephyr  Yes the you are right for the trace .... and so on. The good here is that we only use rows changing and colomun changing that is why it does not affect the eigenvalues

Comment: @Zephyr as example see that $M$ and $M''$ has the same trace. that is what I just explained above

Comment: @Zephyr see my edit. I added a line for you.

Comment: @GuyFsone Only row changing can also change the eigen values $ M= \left[ {
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 3\\
 4 & 5 \\
\end{array} } \right] $ Here if you exchange rows 1 and 2, eigen values change.

Comment: @GuyFsone I didn't downvote it . Maybe your previous answer was not correct.